# TypeError: addToCart is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having issues adding product to cart in react,it's my first time to implement something of this nature.
Here is the code I have

```
const data = {
    productData:[
        {   
            id: 1,
            image: "/assets/images/shop/product.jpeg",
            name: "product1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            image: "/assets/images/shop/product.jpeg",
            name: "product2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            image: "/assets/images/shop/product.jpeg",
            name: "product3"
        },
     ]
}

export default data


import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { addToCart } from '../../../redux/actions/cart-action'
import { Card, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import "../shop.css"

function ProductCard(props) {
    return (
        <div className="product-card col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 pb-5">
                <div className="col-md-12 product overflow-hidden h-100 shadow-lg">
                    <img className="product-img card-img-top img-fluid" src={props.image} alt="product" />
                    <div className="text-center">
                    <div>{props.name}</div>
                    <div> {props.id} </div>
                    <div> {props.desc} </div>
                   
                    <div>#{props.price} </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-success mb-2" onClick={() => dispatch(addToCart(props.id))}>Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id))
    }
}

export default connect (null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductCard)


//Product List

const ProductList = ({products}) => {
  console.warn(data.productData)
    return (
      <div className='shop'>
        <h1 className="text-center">All products</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-10 col-12">
        <section className="mx-4 py-4">
          <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            {data.productData.map((product, index) =>{
              return(
                <ProductCard addToCard={addToCart} image={product.image} name={product.name} desc={product.desc} price={product.price} key={index} />
              )
            })}
             
          </div>

        </section>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <div className="container product-aside d-none d-sm-block py-4">Blah blah Blah . . ./div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    products: state.cart.products,
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (ProductList)
```

And i have the following in the redux store

```
//REDUX
cart-action.js
export const addToCart = (product_id) =>{
    console.log(product_id)
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload:{
           id: product_id,
        }
        
    }
    
}

cart-reducer.js
const initialState = {
    products: [],
    cart: [],
    currentItem: null
  };

    const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case ADD_TO_CART:
                const item = state.products.find(product => product.id === action.payload.id);
                const inCart = state.cart.find(item => item.id ===action.payload.id ? true: false);

                return{
                    ...state,
                    cart: inCart ? state.cart.map(item => item.id ===action.payload.id ? {...item, qty: item.qty + 1} : item) : [...state, {...item, qty: 1}]
                }
    default:
            return state;
        }
    }
export default cartReducer
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: addToCart is not a function onClick
```

Please I need some help to fix this. I have been trying to fix it but I keep running into one problem after another

Comment: How you're calling `ProductCard` ?

Comment: You should import addToCart function if you are not passing it to ProductCard when calling it.

Comment: @Code Maniac I have Product List where I'm calling Product Card, please check

Comment: Thank you @Kian Jalilian. I did just as you suggested but the error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the addToCart is not recognize Why not just pass the addToCart function on props like this

```
<ProductCard addCart={addToCart}>
```

Comment: I add it but the error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are passing addToCart as ProductCard(props, {addToCart}) in ProductCard function. Rather than using dispatch() method you can directly call addToCart action onClick event.
Please try this solution and let me know if it worked

```
    import addToCart from './cart-action.js'


    export default function ProductCard(props) {
        return (
            <div className="product-card col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 pb-5">
                <div className="col-md-12 product overflow-hidden h-100 shadow-lg">
                    <img className="product-img card-img-top img-fluid" src={props.image} alt="product" />
                    <div className="text-center">
                    <div>{props.name}</div>
                    <div> {props.id} </div>
                    <div> {props.desc} </div>
                   
                    <div>#{props.price} </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-success mb-2" onClick={() => dispatch(addToCart(props.id))}>Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here is the simple example

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment-counter' })}>
        Increment counter
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gautam Kothari. Please check. When I used dispatch just as you suggested, I I got the error that  `dispatch` is not defined. I added the part of the code where I'm using product cars (ProductList).

Comment: You should import useDispatch from react-redux, then write code like this: `const dispatch = useDispatch();` Then you can call dispatch and you won't get undefined.

Comment: Added a simple example in answer.  Please refer that